# Cannot call a class as a function, React router show error in console if i use es6 format

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Im using react router extension to define react routes in my application. every thing in working fine, but the issue is that if i use es6 syntax to define class `App.js` than `index.js` "cannot call a class as a function".
if change `App.js` file format to `App.jsx` it resolve my issue.
How does i can define `index.jsx` file in `.js` `es6` format ? or any proper way to resolve this issue? 
these are my react router file and app.js file.
Here is github link of react-router library
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

```
index.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import App from './app/App'

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/> 

  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Now react router file is 
    //  App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

class App extends React.createClass{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
         This is a App.js file write in es6.
        </div>
      )
  }
}


export default App;
```

**Edited: **
I have following webpack loader config

```
{
            test:  /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
             presets:['es2015','react']
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your class should extend `React.Component`, not `React.createClass`.

e.g.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello, world</div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On webpack config file and search for a babel loader that `test` a jsx file. modify `jsx` to `js`

Comment: question updated. with webpack loader config.
i already added loader for js

Answer (score 0):

import only what you need in the component instead of entire library. example below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello, world</div>;
    }
}
```

Also start using env instead of es2015 because env supports all latest ES versions. This is recommended by babel. Install babel-preset-env and uninstall babel-preset-es2015

```
 npm install -d babel-preset-env

{
   test:  /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   loader: 'babel',
   query: {
      presets:['env','react']
   }
}
```